# Query a mongodb for documents having a field set as null but excluding the documents without the field

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, mongo-shell

I'm currently experimenting with mongodb the mongoshell.

I want get documents that have a value null for the tomato.consensus. The following query matches 1991 documents.

```js
    db.movieDetails.find({"tomato.consensus": null}
```

But one of the undesirable side effects is that it will also return the documents with not tomato.concensus field and those with not tomato field at all.

My idea was to use the $exists oeprator. This query returns 362 documents.

```js
    db.movieDetails.find({"tomato.consensus": {$exists: true})
```

My initial idea was to get the documents with a a field tomato.consensus and then working on it to exctract the documents with "tomato.consensus":null. (which does not work):

```js
    $db.movieDetails.find({"tomato.consensus": {$exists: true}}).find({"tomato.consensus": null})
    $uncaught exception: TypeError: db.movieDetails.find(...).find is not a function :
```

Is there a syntax allowing to do both those operation to get rid of the side effect in the mongo shell?

Comment: Use the [$and operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/index.html#and-queries-with-multiple-expressions-specifying-the-same-field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need an $and operator and define multiple filtering criteria

```
db.movieDetails.find( { $and: [ {"tomato.consensus": { $exists: true } }, {"tomato.consensus": null } ] } )
```

Find more details about $and operator and examples [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/).

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use $exist in combination with $and to retrieve documents where "tomato.consensus" exists AND is null :

```
db.movieDetails.find( { $and: [ { "tomato.consensus": null }, { "tomato.consensus": { $exists: true } } ] } )
```

Answer (score 0):

There's the main difference between `null` and `undefined`. Undefined is always null, but in some cases, null isn't undefined.

Checking `undefined` could be done in some ways:

1) `{"tomato.consensus": { $exists: false } }`

2) `{"tomato.consensus": undefined }`

So in order to search null values but not undefined, use query:

```
{'tomato.consensus': null, 'tomato.consensus': { $exists : true }}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It returns both the documents where the field is null and where the field exist. The $and operator is required to achieve the wanted result.

Comment: The query filter will give wrong results. E.g., the two input documents: `tomato : { "c" : "xyz"  } }`, `{ "tomato" : { "c" : null } }` when queried returns both.